# How to call static block in left sidebar in a page in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, static-block, page

How can we call a static block in Magento 2 in a page. In Magento 1 we have this with the following code:

```
<reference name="left">
<block type="cms/block" name="Klantenservice menu" before="-">
    <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>cmsmenu</block_id></action>
</block>    
</reference>
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

**If you want to call static block in page**

Try below code :

```
{{block class="Magento\\Cms\\Block\\Block" block_id="block_identifier"}}
```

**If you want to call in phtml file :**

Try below code :

```
<?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock(\Magento\Cms\Block\Block::class)->setBlockId('block_identifier')->toHtml();?>
```

**Your xml file code should be :**

```
<referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional">
   <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="yourblockid">
       <arguments>
            <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">yourblockid</argument>
       </arguments>
   </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

**At Last if you want to call phtml with your block in cms page :**

Try below code :

```
{{block class="Magento\Modulename\Block\Blockname" template="Magento_Modulename::templatefilename.phtml"}}
```

Refer this link for more details - https://chetansanghani.wordpress.com/2015/11/20/magento2-display-static-block-in-phtml-file-cms-page/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, whatever I try in a page I get the following error: "Please correct the XML data and try again. Element 'layout': Character content other than whitespace is not allowed because the content type is 'element-only'. Line: 1" Any idea?

Comment: @Coen check is there any extra space in your xml file ? or at the starting of xml file ?

Comment: yes there was a comma, I now found somewhere else the answer. See my question above

Comment: @Coen updated the answer please check

Comment: Thanks, uses the one in the xml file and that one by a cms page

Comment: @Coen Thanks happy to help keep helping :)

Comment: done! I'm always here!

Comment: @ManthanDave, i am calling it in success.phtml, its not working for me,main.CRITICAL: Invalid method Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success::__ [] [] got this error in log

Comment: @ManthanDave, is there any way to call static block in external php file

Answer (score 8):

This should work:

```
<referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional">
   <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="yourblockid">
       <arguments>
            <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">yourblockid</argument>
       </arguments>
   </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: Where should I put this xml?

Comment: In the layout file used for the side bar

Answer (score 0):

[image: static Block]
**Above image you can see my block identifier= "product_view_right_sidebar".**

**You need to only replace with your block identifier...**

> here, my block identifier = "product_view_right_sidebar" ==
>   "Your_block_identifier"

```
<referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional">
    <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="product_view_right_sidebar">
        <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">product_view_right_sidebar</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can call the static block with the help of widget. This is one of the good feature of magento.

Here is the list of widgets. We need to create new one so click on “Add Widget” button.

Select type as “CMS Static Block” and choose Design Theme and click on “Continue” button.
[image]

Enter the Widget title and also assign the Store View where you want this block to appear. Also the sort order which displays it in order in list of widgets.

This is very important and good that we can select the specific page or group of pages where we can display this static block.

[image]
Now select our static block created in the widget option. and Save the changes.
[image]
Lets see the static block on the pages.
[image]
Simple !! Do try on your site.