# custom theme implement magento 2.2.6 issue

Tags: magento2.2.6, custom-theme

How to implement custom header, footer HTML design in our custom theme in Magento 2.2.6 version?

Our theme structure:

> app/design/frontend/Cloudways/m2-theme/Magento_Theme

Comment: do  you want custom header and footer in your theme ?

Comment: yes "http://webexpertise.us/wedding/index1" this is my html

Comment: did you try my answer ?

Comment: Yes its working fine And now please let me know for header code(default.xml)

Comment: Did you checked my update ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For adding custom footer you need to create following file:

> app/design/frontend/Cloudways/m2-theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

With following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="footer-container">
            <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Footer" name="footer" template="html/footer.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Now you need to create `footer.phtml` at

> app/design/frontend/Cloudways/m2theme/Magento_Theme/Magento_Theme/templates/html

Now you can call all content using static block in footer.phtml.

**Update I**

If you need custom header you need to add following code same as footer i.e

```
<referenceContainer name="header.container">
    <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Footer" name="myheader" template="html/myheader.phtml" before="-"/>
</referenceContainer>
    <move element="minicart" destination="myheader"/>
    <move element="top.search" destination="myheader"/>
    <move element="logo" as="logo" destination="myheader"/>
    <move element="catalog.topnav" as="nav" destination="myheader"/>
```

Above code will Set new template for header and `move tag` will move existing element to new header.

Now you need to echo this element in your custom header with following code.

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('minicart'); ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml("logo"); ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml("topSearch"); ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml("nav"); ?>
```

[Source](http://oxsoftwares.com/add-custom-header-in-custom-theme-magento2/)

Comment: i create a block in admin  then call in defult.xml file. "<block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="bottom_footer">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="top_video" xsi:type="string">bottom_footer</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>"

Comment: Then please let me know how to call this footer.phtml template.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="footer-container">
            <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Footer" name="footer" template="html/footer.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>

Comment: Its working... please let me know for header template

Comment: i apply same code for header everything ok left navigation menu please let me know how to call dynamic category menu. http://prntscr.com/lal8cb please check my screenshot.

Comment: please see my updates in OP.

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite the existing templates by copying them into your theme and making changes to the template files.

So copy these two files:

> vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/header.phtml
>   vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/footer.phtml

Into your theme:

> app/design/frontend/VENDOR/THEME/Magento_Theme/templates/html/header.phtml
>   app/design/frontend/VENDOR/THEME/Magento_Theme/templates/html/footer.phtml

run below command after your changes if you are in developer mode

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade && php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

run below command after your changes if you are in production mode

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Comment: I am working on live server but i am confused in last step. "php bin/magento setup:upgrade && php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f" please explain

Comment: Because on root bin folder i have 2 text file "htaccess" and "magento"

Comment: you should not be supposed to worry about php bin/magento setup:upgrade && php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f unless and unless if you don't write code directly into pub/static files and you should also not write into core files(vendor/magento), if you don't need to also run static content deploy if you are in production mode(bin/magento deploy:mode:show = prodcution)

Comment: Don't worry your "htaccess" and "magento" files will be there, will not remove from root

Comment: php bin/magento setup:upgrade will do just re-deploy your module, core modules, core/custom theme code into pub/static folder and will compile it into generated and var/view_preprocessed folder and will re-create cache that's it

Answer (score 0):

You can do by overwrite the existing templates by copying them into your theme and making changes to the template files.

So copy these two files:

```
vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/header.phtml
vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/footer.phtml
```

Into your theme:

```
app/design/frontend/VENDOR/THEME/Magento_Theme/templates/html/header.phtml
app/design/frontend/VENDOR/THEME/Magento_Theme/templates/html/footer.phtml
```

Now you can change as per you want and your custom header and footer will complete.

You can create by custom extension also.

Comment: i finished this step already when i put our html in header.phtml file then we have coming both content default and our html.

Comment: From other method also you apply? I think because of 2 overwrite it will call both?

Comment: Please let me know how to call static block in footer template?

Comment: @neharani here is the link.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/156411/how-to-call-static-block-in-left-sidebar-in-a-page-in-magento-2

Comment: Please mark as useful if answer is help you.