# How to edit/create a custom header for Magento 2.3?

Tags: magento2

I am trying to edit the header on my theme but there is not a `header.phtml` or something, just the `default.xml`

How can I overwrite or modify my header content?

BTW the header is displaying inside `<body>` tag

Comment: Go into your admin and turn on template path hints, `stores > configuration > advanced > developer` and then in the debug section. Reload your homepage using template path hints and see what block makes up your header

Comment: Please check https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/247582/custom-theme-implement-magento-2-2-6-issue/247586#247586

Comment: thanks, I already edit the default header :)